# Safari, JavaScript and Copying to the System Clipboard

Tags: javascript, safari, clipboard, safari-extension

I'm doing a Safari extension and would like it to copy something to the users clipboard. Unfortunately all the sources I find talk about cross-platform solutions with Flash or have vague references to execCommand.

Is there a way to do it in Safari with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. There is none. You can file a feature request on Apple's [bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/) if it means something to you. Maybe if we're enough people asking for it they'll finally do it.